# Python request.post() not working when converted to Python Scrapy Request

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I have simple POST request code.

```
headers = {
    dictionary of headers
}

params = (
    ('param1', '0'),
    ('param2', '5668294380'),
    ('param3', '8347915011'),
)

response = requests.post('https://website.com', headers=headers, params=params, data=__data)
```

This works perfectly as standalone Python program.

But I want to do this in Python Scrapy

```
Request(url='https://website.com',callback=self.callback_fun, headers=headers, body=__data, method="POST")
```

It gives me response that URL cannot handle POST request

I tried

```
FormRequest(url='https://website.com',callback=self.callback_fun, headers=headers, body=__data)
```

It gives me same response.

I tried

```
Request(url='https://website.com?' + urllib.urlencode(self.params),callback=self.callback_fun, headers=headers, body=__data, method="POST")
```

But it gives me `400 Bad Request`

Whats wrong with Scrapy? I mean pure Python Script works but in Scrapy does not work.

I think main issue is how to send `params=params` using Scrapy. Scrapy only allows to send Request Payload via `body` parameter

Comment: Check the request being actually sent by trying both methods on https://httpbin.org/ instead of your actual website. There's likely Scrapy overwriting some headers.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I copied that URL from Chrome Dev Tools as cURL. That cURL works perfectly in Shell/Terminal and also I converted that same cURL to Python requests POST using https://curl.trillworks.com/ tool. And that Python code works too!. Only in Scrapy it does not work

Comment: It's not the URL, I am asking you to check it out on httpbin.org and compare the response you get. It's like a mirror, so you know what is the difference in the 2 requests you make from different methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
class scrapy.http.FormRequest(url[, formdata, ...])
```

> Parameters:   formdata (dict or iterable of tuples) – is a dictionary
>   (or iterable of (key, value) tuples) containing HTML Form data which
>   will be url-encoded and assigned to the body of the request.

in HTTP, if you want to post data, the data is set in the request body and  encoded. you can encode the dict you self or use Scrapy `FormRequest`:

```
class FormRequest(Request):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    formdata = kwargs.pop('formdata', None)
    if formdata and kwargs.get('method') is None:
        kwargs['method'] = 'POST'

    super(FormRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if formdata:
        items = formdata.items() if isinstance(formdata, dict) else formdata
        # encode dict here
        querystr = _urlencode(items, self.encoding)
        if self.method == 'POST':
            # set message header
            self.headers.setdefault(b'Content-Type', b'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            # set message body
            self._set_body(querystr)
        else:
            self._set_url(self.url + ('&' if '?' in self.url else '?') + querystr)
```

----------------------------update--------------

in requests code:

```
response = requests.post('https://website.com', headers=headers, params=params, data=__data)
```

it first adds the parameter to the URL the post data to the modified URL. you should change you URL. you can get the URL by:

```
print(response.url)
```

Comment: I am still getting `HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL`

Comment: this is code `yield FormRequest(url='https://website', callback=self.parse_response, headers=self.headers, formdata=self.params, body=__data)`

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you ... you want me to change URL? or what ? also where i should put code `class FormRequest`??? in Spider file?

Comment: @Umair in you `requests` code, print the `response.url` to check where the data is posted. that is the real url you need to use in Scrapy.

Comment: `response.url` is `https://website.com/ko/website/g?authuser=0&__u=5668294380&__c=8347915011` but when doing it with `FormRequest` Scrapy prints ` DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <POST https://website.com/website> from <POST https://website.com/ko/website/g/?authuser=0&__u=5668294380&__c=8347915011>
` `DEBUG: Crawled (405) <POST https://website.com/website> (referer: https://website.com/ko/website/Home?__u=5668294380&__c=8347915011&authuser=0)`

Comment: Scrapy shows `Redirecting (301) to <POST https://website.com/website> from <POST https://website.com/ko/website/g/?authuser=0&__u=5668294380&__c=8347915011>`

Comment: That means URL is right, but maybe scrapy not sending headers or something else is missing